# What is the subsitute for frames?

Tags: html, iframe, frame

Lets say I have a web site with 50 web pages. Each page consists of

1. A Header
2. Navigation
3. Left Side Content
4. Right Side Content
5. Footer

Without using

1. Frames
2. Server side programming
3. Third part tools and softwares
4. Frameworks

I would need to put the code (HTML Markup) for each of these 5 sections in each of those 50 pages? What happened to the term "Code Once, Use Again & Again"? Also If I want to change any thing, I would need to change it at 50 places. This is just reduntant. Can I use as such.

```
<object type="text/html" height="100%" width="100%" data="header.html"></object>
```

Excuse my stupid questions. Learning the hardway!

Comment: What's your problem with frames, server side programming, and literally every tool and framework in the universe?  That kinda limits your options a bit.  If it's not server side, it's client side, which means javascript or frames, which have clear drawbacks.  You really should use SSI or something similar.

Comment: Beacause I am new to Web Development and starting my journey with HTML/XHTML, CSS, XML, Javascript, AJAX and than finally to PHP along with SQL (And In That Order)

Comment: Good to hear.  There's more to web than just client side.  A language like PHP is essential for a robust site along the lines that you described in your question.

Comment: And regarding frameworks, I hate them. I don't want to to become a copy paste programmer. I think, and that is my personal opnion, that freworks should be only used by advnaced experienced and professionals. For example CSS frameworks such as 960 and others just let you design and develop web sites with out you having to understand CSS at a deaper level. They save time sure but for a new guy like me, fisrt become atleast comformatable with CSS and than use them if you have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You describe the exact use case for a server-side language.

Let me explain you the problem with your approach. If you do your site this way, having an `index.html` and those other 5 parts you include through either `object` or `iframe`, this will mean 6 requests to your server (which is certainly not a good practice).

Things will happen like this:

- Browser requests your `index.html`
- Parses it and finds it also needs to request `header.html` and four others
- Requests all those 5 htmls from the server

Instead, you could just request `index.php` for example (if you use PHP), let PHP construct **ONE** HTML resource (possibly including other PHP files, like `header.php`) and send it to the browser, which will happily display it.

You don't have to break your learning order, only use some small parts for this specific purpose (using only one command at all). Be flexible, you will find it very useful in this business :).

To give you an example:

*index.php*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
<body>

<?php include 'header.php'; ?>

<?php include 'navigation.php'; ?>

...

<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

In your PHP files, you can have only simple HTML, only the file extension will be different. To write PHP commands you can use `<?php whatever ?>`

Comment: Thanks mate. I guess that is the exact reason why I have not seen the usage of <object> for this purpose and it should not be used in this manner. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

> I would need to put the code (HTML Markup) for each of these 5 sections in each of those 50 pages?

Yes

> What happened to the term "Code Once, Use Again & Again"?

You rejected all the techniques that make that possible in HTML (well, unless you count writing your own template engine from scratch (no third party tools) and running it at build time instead of on demand (no server side code), or using JavaScript (which is insane)).

> Can I use as such. `<object type="text/html" height="100%" width="100%" data="header.html"></object>`

That is effectively an `<iframe>`, just with fewer features and weaker browser support.

Comment: Not sounding rude of something as I am new to this. I Tested the same on IE9, FF4, GC10, AS5 and Opera11 and it works like a charm. However of all the books That I have read and other learning resources such as CBT, I have never seen done like this which makes me think that I am missing something. Just wanting to know why it cant be done like this in a manner similiar to the using of <form> related Elements should not be used for navigation.

Comment: @JAA, well for one thing you'd be making *6 different requests* to the server, adding in travel time twice (to and from the server) *for each request*. Your page will also have to readjust its layout *for every single request*. That's not even touching on the complexity of maintaining this nightmare of an application, losing bookmarks, etc

Answer (score 1):

You could also achieve the goal by just combining different parts, meaning that you write your header in one file, navigation to another and content to third file and then combine these to actual webpages. (basically making your own template engine). Such as (in UNIX)

```
cat header.html navigation.html body1.html > page1.html
```

Not the ideal solution but this way you only need change once. But for anything real, already suggested server-side scripting is best option usually.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use server side programming (which is what it was built for mind you), your only choice is an AJAX call to fill in the common elements at run time.

This however will not provide a very good user experience, as the page slowly loads itself AFTER it seemed to finish loading.

You *really* should use server side programming for this.

Comment: Thanks mate. But it is a long learning process and I want to learn HTML/XHTML before I jump to AJAX

Answer (score 0):

One common solution is Server Side Includes (SSI), which allows you to include one block of html markup in multiple pages (among other things).  If you're using PHP, definitely consider PHP includes: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp.

Comment: Thanks Eric, Will take up SSI now. Did not even know it existed.