# HTML redundancy in navigation

Tags: html, navigation, redundancy

Coming from C++ I was taught that code repetition is a giant red flag of doing something wrong. Now when I make a navigation menu in HTML I have to copy it into each page I want it in, violating everything I've known about clean code. Is this just the way HTML will be or would it be cleaner to define the navigation menu in a separate HTML file and use an Iframe to display it into the pages?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834684/what-is-the-subsitute-for-frames

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with your sentiment. It would be cleaner to put your navbar in a single html file, and load it separately. However, I would suggest you use some server-side script (like PHP) to put all the html together, rather than loading it in an iframe.

You can make a very simple PHP script that will concatenate html from several files, then output it to the browser. If this is possible in your case, that's what I would do.

Comment: Definitly go for serverside scripting instead of an iFrame

Comment: Please, please, please, @Jake, don't use an iframe for this.

Comment: @mdepolli haha I wont, I wont, this is why I ask! I am relatively new to web development so it was just the first thing I thought of

Comment: recommendations as to what script I can use to do this on a Tomcat server? This is all within a JSF project

Comment: As far as I know, JSF should already support what you're trying to accomplish. Have a look at [this article](http://www.jsfcentral.com/articles/facelets_3.html). Basically, what you'll be doing is reading the contents of the navbar's html file, then writing that to a variable in the main page's template using a template engine. This is a bit more complicated than simply concatenating, but if you can figure this out, it's cleaner still.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just working on static html pages, use server side includes if you're able:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes

In a nutshell, define your code in a separate file, each template then just references that file wherever you tell it to.

There's a hundred and one different ways of 'including' a template style file in a page, just depends on what kind of setup your host has I guess.